# what is pppm_lkg, pppm_dyn in McPAT?

Tags: cpu, simulation, simulator

Is there anybody working with McPAT?
Each power component in McPAT is actually multiplied by a constant array named pppm_lkg. They did not provide any information about this. They used a constant value only. 
Could anyone tell me the meaning of pppm? Where does the value come from?

Comment: [McPAT basic_circuit.h](https://github.com/HewlettPackard/mcpat/blob/74d4759f3ba2dff8f5a69e07a68efdb46b42fb8c/cacti/basic_circuit.h) comment on line 249 says that in `set_pppm` it means "set power point product mask."